# How to detect changes in child component with respect to changes in the base component - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular9

I have a component `profile.component.ts` in which there's a variable, `this.candidate`, which subscribes to and gets updated like this

```
 this.candidateSub = this.store.select(selectCandidateState).subscribe((candidateState) => {
    this.candidate = candidateState;
 })
```

This component acts like a base component and there's a child component that extends this component,

```
export class SkillsComponent extends profile implements OnInit, OnDestroy
```

Now I want to have another variable in this child component that updates itself whenever `this.candidate` gets updated in the base component. Something like this:

`this.candidateSkills = this.candidate.skills`

The problem is I can't get it done simply by declaring `this.candidateSkills = this.candidate.skills` in `ngOnit` as it doesn't *watch and listen* to changes and update itself when `this.candidate` gets updated in base component.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parent component:

```
this.storeObservable = this.store.select(selectCandidateState)

this.candidateSub = this.storeObservable.subscribe((candidateState) => {
  this.candidate = candidateState;
})
```

In child component:

```
this.storeObservable.subscribe((candidateState) => {
  // do something
})
```